# async Task crashes application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, void

I have the following 2 methods, CheckForUpdatesExecute() is called when my ViewModel loads, which in turn calls GetLAtestVErsionAsync()

```
       private async void CheckForUpdatesExecute()
        {
            char[] MyChar = { 'v' };
            var _latestVersionFull = await GetLatestVersionAsync();
            var _latestVersion = _latestVersionFull.TrimStart(MyChar);
            Version latestVersion = new Version(_latestVersion);
            _updatesAvailable = latestVersion > CurrentVersion;
            ((DelegateCommand)InstallUpdate).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        private async Task<string> GetLatestVersionAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/vnd.github+json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Test");

                var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/latest");
                var document = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(stream);
                if (!document.RootElement.TryGetProperty("tag_name", out var tagNameProperty))
                {
                    return "0.0.0.0";
                }

                return tagNameProperty.GetString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "0.0.0.0";
            }
        }
```

If I throw in a breakpoint here, I can see the app crashing/locking up with no error or exception displayed.

```
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/latest");
```

I had toyed with changing async void to async task, but from what I understand Task requires a return and I have nothing to return.

Comment: Check your Exception Handling settings in Visual Studio when you use VS and mark all Exception as 'Break when thrown'. Then debug again. Maybe you get more to see what the problem is. And the return of CheckForUpdatesExecute should be Task even if it returns nothing. If you haven't yet tried that put a breakpoint in the catch handler.

Comment: ​As a side note the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Comment: *"I can see the app crashing/locking up with no error or exception displayed."* -- The term *crash* is used when a process terminates with an error. In your case the process does not terminate. It stays alive but sleeps forever, correct? The term that describes this behavior is *deadlock*.

Comment: Hey

@Ralf - I took a look at that, but nothing was actually being thrown.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'll check out what you said about HttpClient :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try changing below code:

```
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/latest");
```

to

```
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/latest").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Please refer to [ConfigureAwait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=net-6.0).

Comment: This actually partially resolved my issue! 

.ConfigureAwait(false) is what I was looking for, but I needed it here

```
                var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/repos///releases/latest").ConfigureAwait(false);
                var document = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Updated answer based on your suggestion. What other issue are you facing?

Comment: Nothing, that was all :) Thanks for your help!